# Dealing with has_many through checkboxes in a nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to add has_many_through relationship through a form nested in a parent model. I can't figure out if this is possible?

The nested form works ok without the checkboxes. And the checkboxes work fine when they're outside the nested form.

```
= semantic_form_for @raduser do |f|
  %ul       
    %li
      = f.text_field :expiration, :placeholder => 'Expiration Date', :id => 'expiration_date'
    - f.fields_for :radcheck do |builder|
      = builder.text_field :username, :placeholder => 'Stuff'
      -Radgroup.all.each do |group|
        %li
          = check_box_tag 'radcheck[radgroup_ids]', group.id, @radcheck.radgroup_ids.include?(group.id)
          = group.groupname          

    %li
      = f.submit
```

This throws an error:

```
 undefined method `radgroup_ids' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007faaa24c2468>
```

I've got the models set up fine I think as all values save perfectly without the checkboxes

--- EDIT ADDED MODELS ---

Radusers have many Radcheck (singular due to legacy db). Radcheck has many radgroups through radusergroup.

```
class Raduser < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :radcheck, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :radcheck, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:value].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true   

end

class Radcheck < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'radcheck'

  attr_accessible :attribute_name, :username, :value, :op, :radgroupcheck_id, :radcheck_serial, :radgroup_ids

  belongs_to :raduser

  has_many :radusergroup, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :radgroup, :through => :radusergroup

end

class Radgroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'radgroup'

  has_many :radusergroup, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :radcheck, :through => :radusergroup

end


class Radusergroup < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :radcheck
belongs_to :radgroup

end
```

-- UPDATE TWO --

```
 def new
  @radcheck = Radcheck.new
  ...      
 end

 def create
  @radcheck = Radcheck.new(params[:radcheck])
  ...
 end
```

--- UPDATE 3 ---

My db currently looks like this:

```
 +----------------+-----------------------+----------+------+
 | radcheck_id    | radgroup_id           | priority | id   |
 +----------------+-----------------------+----------+------+
 | 8              | 3                     |        1 |    1 |
 | 4              | 9                     |        0 |    2 |
 | 22             | 4                     |        1 |    3 |
 | 2              | 6                     |        1 |    4 |
```

I have the solution suggested below working.

What I was hoping to do was insert the radcheck_username and radgroup_groupname into the db, not the radcheck_id:

```
+----------------+-----------------------+----------+------+
| ...username    | --groupname           | priority | id   |
+----------------+-----------------------+----------+------+
| user123344     | group88888            |        1 |    1 |
| shushQb        | 30-minutes            |        0 |    2 |
| forty          | gigiig                |        1 |    3 |
| snang          | ps-staff              |        1 |    4 |
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Need to see your models if possible.

Comment: @Ryan, have just updated my question. Thanks

Comment: A **has_many :through** will not generate the **something_ids** method. Why do you have this **Radusergroup** class? Is there any useful information on it or just the ids?

Comment: Working on a legacy db which stores the join in radusergroup. I was thinking about writing my own action to deal with this. In its current state, it actually uses the username from radcheck and groupname from radgroup (instead of radcheck_id and radgroup_id). Bit of a pain.

Comment: In reality, it's raduser that's probably irrelevant. Am only using it because of the nested fields. If there was a way to add many radcheck with same username but different attributes, I'd scrap it.

Comment: Okay... I think I see what's happening, but I need to know what's stored in @radcheck before I can take a stab at answering.  I can see that it's a relation, but can you show me the line that's actually setting the value of @radcheck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you're trying to access Radcheck's various Radgroups through a method that isn't defined yet.  I can see a couple of solutions to this.  One would be to add the missing **radgroup_ids** method to your model.  Alternatively, I think you could call include? on Radchecks **radgroups** relation.

**Solution A**

Within your Radcheck class, define:

```
def radgroup_ids
  radgroups.map(&:id)
end
```

**Solution B**

Make a minor change to the way you're checking for included Radgroups

```
@radcheck.radgroups.include?(group)
```

Comment: That seems to work. Can you tell me also if it's possible to insert a different value other than the ID? I'd prefer to use the username (for example).

Comment: If you're referring to Solution A, you can use the to_proc shortcut (&:symbol) for any method radgroup provides.  If that's not what you mean, then I'm not quite sure what you're asking.  Do you want an array of usernames to come out of your radgroup collection, or are you trying to use username somewhere else?  Since I can't see the actual database, I don't know which models provide which properties.

Comment: This is getting too convoluted for me to be of much further help.  Best I can suggest is to add a before_save filter to your Raduser model that looks at the information you've pulled in from the form, looks up the user and group names that you want to store, and sets the corresponding `username` and `groupname` attributes on the model.  Assuming you've added them to your table, they'll then be saved just like any other attributes on the model.

Comment: Hi. I agree, I'm the end I sorted By adjusting the foreign :and primary keys.